# Highlight part of the string by position at string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I send a request with a sample string like "This is a test string, I just use it with a smile and wish a very nice day to you all".

I have a JSON array as a response which has the following view:

```json
{
   "words" : [
     [
         {
             "Start": 5
         },
         {
             "Length": 9
         }
      ],
      [
         {
             "Start": 61
         },
         {
             "Length": 24
         }
      ],
   ]
}
```

Start means the index of the letter, length - the length of the sentence.

How is it possible to get highlighted output of the string using Javascript, e.g:

```
"This <span>is a test</span> string, I just use it with a smile and wish a very <span>nice day to you all</span>"
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has been closed. It only asks a single question and shows input with expected ouput. How does it need to be more focused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

It could be cleaner if you can change the response structure to something less verbose.

```js
const text = 'This is a test string, I just use it with a smile and wish a very nice day to you all';
const response = {
   "words" : [
     [
         {
             "Start": 5
         },
         {
             "Length": 9
         }
      ],
      [
         {
             "Start": 61
         },
         {
             "Length": 24
         }
      ],
   ]
};

function highlight(text, words) {
  const chars = text.split('');
  
  for (let i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const start = words[i][0]['Start'];
    const length = words[i][1]['Length'];
    
    chars.splice(start + length, 0, '</span>')
    chars.splice(start, 0, '<span>');
  }
  
  return chars.join('');
}

console.log(highlight(text, response.words));
```